# Anime character of a girl with black hair, animal ears, pink clothes and with a pink flower in her hair

Tags: story-identification, anime, character-identification

What is the below anime character of a girl with black hair, wearing pink clothes and with a pink flower in their hair? She also appears to have animal ears, which would suggest that this is from a fantasy anime. What anime is she from?

[image: The anime character in question]

Answer (score 7):

This looks like [Kuon](https://myanimelist.net/character/129766/Kuon) from [*Utawarerumono*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utawarerumono) (which has a visual novel, and an anime, and a manga):

[image: Kuon]